# Digitize map using .png image and draw a circle with known lat./long. as center by inputing radius value in python

Tags: python, image-processing, digitization

I have a .png map image which contains location of handpumps in given village. there are 70 location value.I want to do following in python (had already done similar thing in matlab previously) -

1. digitize .png image of map(had already done similar thing in matlab previously) but need to do in python now.
2. draw a circle with transparent color with given lat./long. point as center and radius given by me.

Any help will be highly appreciated. just started doing this, so will keep on updating this post as i search and find solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done with help of converting simialr R code...

```
def bubbles(lat,long,re,colvar,wellnum,txt):
   
    s=list(map(lambda x: x *1.2, re))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    lc=plt.scatter(lat, long, s,c=colvar,cmap="coolwarm", alpha=0.8, edgecolors="grey", linewidth=2)
# Add titles (main and on axis)
    for i in range(0,len(wellnum)):
        plt.text(lat[i],long[i],' {1}ft\n{0}\n{2}R2'.format(wellnum[i],re[i],str(round(txt[i],2))))
    plt.xlabel("LAT")
    plt.ylabel("LONG")
    plt.title("B")
    axcb = fig.colorbar(lc)
    axcb.set_label('Pe')
    
    plt.show()
    return fig
```